# A green checkmark animation in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using React to create an animation of a check mark being drawn: similar to this : http://jsfiddle.net/1faqu4yt/ . I'm not very familiar with how `React` does animations, I've looked through their site's API but couldn't find much. Any examples of simple animation for React would be helpful. Or would it just be better to use `CSS` instead?

Comment: (Why are you using React to do this? You might find just using an animated GIF to be sufficient and more efficient).

Answer (score 1):

You can use that code almost as-is.

The two changes:

- wrap it in a function
- provide a stop mechanism

```
function animate(canvas){
    var start = 100;
    var mid = 145;
    var end = 250;
    var width = 22;
    var leftX = start;
    var leftY = start;
    var rightX = mid - (width / 2.7);
    var rightY = mid + (width / 2.7);
    var animationSpeed = 20;
      var isStopped = false;

      var stop = function(){
        isStopped = true;
      };

    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    ctx.lineWidth = width;
    ctx.strokeStyle = 'rgba(0, 150, 0, 1)';

    for (i = start; i < mid; i++) {
        var drawLeft = window.setTimeout(function () {
            if (isStopped) return;
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.moveTo(start, start);
            ctx.lineTo(leftX, leftY);
            ctx.stroke();
            leftX++;
            leftY++;
        }, 1 + (i * animationSpeed) / 3);
    }

    for (i = mid; i < end; i++) {
        var drawRight = window.setTimeout(function () {
            if (isStopped) return;
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.moveTo(leftX, leftY);
            ctx.lineTo(rightX, rightY);
            ctx.stroke();
            rightX++;
            rightY--;
        }, 1 + (i * animationSpeed) / 3);
    }
```

The component is fairly straight forward. You render a canvas to draw onto. You start the animation when it mounts, or on some event. You stop it if it's unmounted.

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(){
    super();
  }

  componentDidMount(){
    var canvas = React.findDOMNode(this.refs.canvas);
    this.stop = animate(canvas);
  }

  componentWillUnmount(){
    this.stop();
  }

  render(){
    return (
      <div>
        <canvas height="400" ref="canvas" />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

### Alternatives

You mentioned CSS, which is usually preferred for its simplicity, but it'd be difficult to do this animation in CSS. You'd be animating two white divs to cover up parts of the checkmark that aren't yet visible.

The other option is SVG. React has built in support for SVG, so you could do everything declaratively from render, and just update the elapsed time in state. Or you could render the initial SVG, and animate it manually in componentDidMount.

With animation, performance usually takes precedence over code clarity. For example, running hundreds of timers is pretty slow. Redrawing the same line on the canvas over and over is pretty slow, and canvas is pretty slow (especially in firefox and mobile).

The fastest way to do this is likely animating `<div>`s in JS, or SVGs in JS.

Comment: Of course you're not wrong but the idea of animating something like this with javascript makes me shudder :)

Comment: It's a small leap from describing styles or dom in JS, and the limits of css (performance, physics based animations, gestures, etc.) make it worth considering.